# Cipher with painted cells

Tags: cipher

I have no idea what is going on in this puzzle. It is an extra credit thing for my class and we were not taught how to solve it.

[image: painted cells]

Comment: $2^5 > 26$, so that fits quite well with columns being characters... the empty are likely spaces. Didn't investigate, just a hunch.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 12):

> Well, as Carl Löndahl pointed out, every column could be interpreted as a character. If black is 1 and white is 0, and the most significant digit is the top one, we can translate from binary code to this:
>  `25 1 8 1 8 1 0 25 15 21 0 6 15 21 14 4 0 12 5`
>  Which gives us a slightly weird message if we take " " = 0, "A" = 1, "B" = 2 etc.:
>  `YAHAHA YOU FOUND LE`
>  Maybe "LE" is a mistake and it should be "ME" (L is just one step from M).

Comment: PS: Found with the help of www.dcode.fr (though it isn't really necessary for this simple substitution.